# Formatting tools keep disappearing...

Tags: bug, status-declined

I am talking about the add image, url etc. Am I the only one? I have a post that needs an image but I can't :P

I made a screenshot and it is on my PC but can't use the upload tool. Had to use good old imageshack.

Just now formatting tools came back but seconds later they are missing again.

[image]

Comment: I get this with Chrome too, seems to work fine with Firefox though.

Comment: Works perfect on Firefox but not on Chrome 12.

Comment: Are you using a Dev build of Chrome? I'm using the main repo's chromium-browser and haven't seen anything similar.

Comment: default repo one; reverted back to ff for now :)

Comment: I take that back. I'm seeing it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We do not support beta browsers. We only support officially released browsers.

Chrome sometimes needs it's cache cleared, go to the wrench menu, then preferences, or just this URL:

```
chrome://settings/clearBrowserData
```

And clear the content settings:

[image]

Comment: mine is the default one from the repos.

Comment: @rinz then clear your browser cache -- for some reason Chrome 11 likes to serve stale cache after upgrading.

Comment: Edit the browser cache part into your answer, @Jeff, I think it maybe of help for quite a few users.

Comment: Shortcut for the screenshot: control-shift-delete

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:** This is only happening on latest Chrome 12 Dev. As of version **12.0.742.30 dev** it has been solved.

Comment: It's happening to me now on 11.0.696.57 (82915) Ubuntu 11.04.

Comment: O.o well i was referring to going to the previous 12.x but i did not know 11 had the same problem. So it is bad actually.

Comment: And clearing the cache fixes it. Reporting a chromium bug...

Comment: I installed Ubuntu 11.04 again so i think that was an awesome cache cleaner ;)

Comment: @CYREX, but of course OS reinstallaton's the ultimate cache cleanup! But seriously, you took an extreme measure.

Comment: Forgot to mention i bought a new computer to solve the problem...in another state....of another country. Just in case ;)

Comment: As of version 12.0.742.30 dev it has been solved

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record: I did have the [same problem in firefox](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1434/why-did-the-dhtml-content-on-stackexchange-cease-to-work-all-of-a-sudden/1435#1435). As well the solution was clearing my browser cache (including cookies).